# Saved file location from Ionic Capacitor Filesystem writeFile when running on Web browser via ionic serve

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem

Taken from the site, the example code is:

```
import { Filesystem, Directory, Encoding } from '@capacitor/filesystem';

const writeSecretFile = async () => {
  await Filesystem.writeFile({
    path: 'secrets/text.txt',
    data: "This is a test",
    directory: Directory.Documents,
    encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
  });
};
```

When I run the program via Web / `ionic serve`
Where can I find the saved file: `secrets/text.txt` on my Computer?

Answer (score 3):

The [plugin's source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/main/filesystem/src/web.ts) (Capacitor v4.0.1) reveals the web plugin tries to use IndexedDB, and fails if IndexedDB is not available.

Check out the [initDb()](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/main/filesystem/src/web.ts#L63) method:

```
if (!('indexedDB' in window)) {
    throw this.unavailable("This browser doesn't support IndexedDB");
}
```

Using the [example from the documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem#example), you can check the result in the Developper tools:

[image: IndexedDB content in DevTools]

Capacitor uses static names ("DOCUMENTS", "CACHE", "DATA", etc) as the counterpart to native paths for the web.

Note that the fact that it is not explained in the documentation might indicate that the implementation could change at any time.